# Creating a Stem and Whisker Graph with Just the Whiskers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a chart like the one I've drawn in the attached photo. Where it takes the min and max of the "y" values in the rows. How may I go about doing this? I've been trying several different formats including box and whisker and I am just not doing something right.

[image]

Comment: The way your data is laid out, I would look at a "Stock" chart.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not in the correct format for a box-and-whisker plot.  The first solution I found is not exactly what you want, but it's an option:

## All box, no whisker

You can doctor another chart to your liking.  This is a regular stacked column chart:
[image: Excel stacked column chart]

You add two data series', one for each Y value.  Then you set Series1 to `No Fill`, Series2 I can't seem to change the column width, but I can increase the gap between between columns to 500%:
[image: Excel box no whisker chart]

## All whisker, no box

This requires even more trickery.  Firstly I set up two new columns of data, a midpoint `(y1 + y2) / 2` and a half-value `(y2 - y1) / 2`.  I then set up a bar graph using only the midpoint values:
[image: Excel column chart midpoint]

Next add error bars to it.  For me it's under Chart Design > Add Chart Element > Errors Bars > More Errors Bars Options.  In the Format Error Bars you can set a custom Error Amount:
[image: Excel custom error bars]

I set the Positive Error and Negative Error to be my half-value.

Then just disappear the column again (Format Data Series, set Fill to No Fill) and you have your whisker graph:
[image: Excel whisker graph]